# Define globally-includable CMake function?

Tags: cmake

I want to define a custom function which can be used globally with the `include` function. Is there some location that I can put additional cmake sources which can be included globally?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of
[find_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_file) and
[CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_MODULE_PATH)

```
find_file( common_file File.cmake path1 path2 path3 )
if( common_file STREQUAL "common_file-NOTFOUND" )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Missing common cmake file" )
else()
    LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH common_file )
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than adding it as a file in CMake's own install directory (not recommended), you can define [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_MODULE_PATH) at the start of your CMakeLists.txt (or via the command line using `-D`) to provide the location of directories to be searched for CMake modules.

Comment: The reason I want it to be global is that the "global" include would be installed by another CMake project, which the child projects depend on anyway. All my "child" projects would need to use the same file, so I'd rather have a way to use a shared module. This is really what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, except for installing to CMake's own module path (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules).  If you're working on your own, it may be OK, but I think this is generally a bad idea since your module would then appear to be an official CMake one.  It would probably also get removed when CMake is upgraded.